# Java Swing JFrame diposition

Tags: java, swing, jframe, anonymous-class

I have one `JFrame`. That `JFrame` has a window listener for closing events which are intercepted and provide the user with options prior to closing the entire program.

Must I call `dipose()` on a `JFrame` or am I safe to call only `System.exit(0)`?  Secondly, should I only call `dipose()` on a `JFrame` or should I call `dipose()` followed by `System.exit(0)`?

Comment: Can you post some code.

Comment: I did not realize I had a member of my class but was declaring and making a new member with the same name.  That cleared it up.

Comment: Editing your question as you've done makes previous answers invalid. Please don't do this. If you need to edit it, leave the original question and add new information to the bottom.

Comment: Clarified my question to specifically address what I wanted to ask although a previous comment addressed a compile error I caught.  My apologies and I won't change my question.

Comment: IF you only have one frame why not just `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`? That will handle the exit for you

Comment: Because I want to give the user an option to do something productive before closing the program down.

Comment: 1) Did you look at the API for the `setDefaultCloseOperation(...)` method? What values are allowed? What methods would you think would be invoked for each of the different operations? 2) Already answered in my original response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is must I call dipose() on my JFrame object or can I safely call System.ext(0)?

Why would you ask this? You should solve you compile problem first, and then decide what approach you want to use. Don't use System.exit() just because you don't know how to get rid of a compile error

> am using a WindowAdapter as

There is no need for you to keep a variable in order to reference your frame. The best approach to access the frame is to get the frame from the WindowEvent:

```
JFrame frame = (JFrame)event.getSource();
```

To answer your original question I would use dispose(). It will eventually invoke System.exit() if it is the last frame open in your application.

Edit:

> I want to give the user an option to do something productive before closing the program down

You can check out [Closing an Appliction](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for more ideas on this topic.

Comment: I cleared up my compile error.  Now I just want to know must I use `dipose()` on a `JFrame`.